# Apply relative radial distortion function to image w/o knowing anything about the camera

Tags: opencv, distortion

I've a radial distortion function which gives me relative distortion from 0 (image center) to the relative full image field (field height 1) in percent. For example this function would give me a distortion of up to 5% at the full relative field height of 1.

I tried to use this together with opencv undistort function to *apply* distortion but don't know how to fill the matrices.

As said, I've a source image only and don't know anything about the camera parameters like focal length, except that I know the distortion function.

How should I set the matrix in cv2.undistort(src_image, matrix, ...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenCv routine that's easier to use in your case is [cv::remap](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gab75ef31ce5cdfb5c44b6da5f3b908ea4), not undistort.

In the following I assume your distortion purely radial. Similar considerations apply if you have it already decomposed in (x, y).

So you have a distortion function `d(r)` of the distance `r = sqrt((x - x_c)^2 + (y - y_c)^2)` of a pixel `(x, y)` from the image center `(x_c, y_c)`. The function expresses the relative change of the radius `r_d` of a pixel in the distorted image from the undistorted one `r`: `(r_d - r) / r = d(r)`, or, equivalently, `r_d = r * (1 - d(r))`.

If you are given a distorted image, and want to remove the distortion, you need to invert the above equation (i.e. solve it analytically or numerically), finding the value of `r` for every `r_d` in the range of interest. Then you can trivially create two arrays, `map_x` and `map_y`, that represent the mapping from distorted to undistorted coordinates: for a given pair `(x_d, y_d)` of integer pixel coordinates in the distorted image, you compute the associated `r_d = sqrt(((x_d - x_c)^2 + (y_d - y_c)^2)`, then the corresponding `r` as function of `r_d` from solving the equation, go back to `(x, y)`, and assign `map_x[y_d, x_d] = x; map_y[y_d, x_d] = y`. Finally, you pass those to cv::remap.

Comment: thanks - this does perfectly the job and is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @thinknicethings you should accept the answer if you find it useful - it helps other SO users find it in search.